# Show icon in taskbar for hidden windows

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0, window, taskbar

When I set the main window's visibility to hidden, No icon is shown in taskbar, so I have no control over the window to show it again. I want for the application's icon to be visible even when I hide the window, and to show the window when I click it's button in the taskbar. (something like minimize behavior)
How can I achieve that using WPF and .Net 4.0 in C#?
**Edit:** I mean the icon in taskbar (usually in the left and middle of the horizontal taskbar) not the notifyicon in system tray.

Comment: Either of these might help: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/01b6f20c-d4fb-4956-a3f6-d5e5d91bd239/wpf-menu-for-system-tray-icon?forum=wpf or http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0913ae1a-7efc-4d7f-a7f7-58f112c69f66/c-application-system-tray-icon

Comment: @SepehrM, have you considered simply using `this.WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;` or are you actually asking about tray icon?

Comment: @drew_w, I meant taskbar icon, not the notifyicon in system tray.

Comment: @Yuriy My problem is that I can't minimize the window because its dialogs and etc will be minimized too. I just want to set the window's visibility to hidden, instead of actually minimizing it.

Answer (score 2):

So, based on "comments" section, what you are looking to do is minimize or hide a window but still show some windows or dialogues that the window opens. First if you want to keep your window in the task bar, you should minimize with:

```
this.WindowState = WindowState.Minimized
```

That can be called from anywhere within the form. As you mentioned, though, this will <strike>close</strike> hide any dialogues that have this window set as the parent. The key, then is to not use this window as the parent. Lets say your dialogues inherit from form. You want to use:

```
newWindow.Show();
```

I am guessing that you are calling "ShowDialog", which ties the window state to the parent window state. Try this out and hopefully it will help!

**Edit**

One more note: the same is actually true of MessageBoxes, but the way to control the parent form is with the first parameter of the MessageBox.Show() call. If you pass in a form as the first parameter, that will be the parent, otherwise the parent will not be set.

Comment: Thanks, But actually besides the dialogs, I have AvalonDock's docking manager in the main window. When the user minimizes the window, all the floating panels are hidden. So I'm hiding the window instead of actually minimizing it to prevent those floating app from hiding. Is there a better approach than hiding the window?

Comment: Looking at the code for AvalonDock on CodePlex it looks like "FloatingWindow" at least inherits from Window. My guess is that if you look at the options or are willing to get into the AvalonDock code a bit you will find a way to minimize the main window but still show the panels (which are now probably their own windows). The same principle I mentioned above should still apply. Good luck!

Comment: Although there are multiple patches related to this issue, none of them seem to work for me. I'll still look into it and see if I can come up with a solution. So there is no way to directly control (show/hide) taskbar icon? I'm aware of this article but couldn't find anything useful: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff699128.aspx

Comment: I'm not really aware of anything specific, though you might be able to use a splash form type concept somehow.